# Error at the end of installation -- GRUB -- Dual boot w/ Windows 8.1

Tags: system-installation, settings

I decided to install elementary OS on my Lenovo G410 (no touch). I downloaded and burned the installation media and booted from it. The installation went fine until the very end, when an error popped up saying that GRUB had failed to install. When I rebooted, my computer went straight to Windows 8.1, without me being able to boot from Ubuntu.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried installing with "internet connection"?

Comment: please post it in English, no Spanish please =)